# How to get all android device hardware specifications

Tags: android, hardware, specifications

Im trying to get and display all device specifications using Android api.

Few details im able to get like Battery Details, Bluetooth details, and Device details using 
android.os.BatteryManager, android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter, and android.os.Build API classes..

I also want to get other details like Display, Memory, Camera, Sensors etc

but i didn't find any help to get these specifications.

Please let me know how to get these details.

Thank you.